# How to make the moment(date) an Object Key and the moment(time) is the value;

Tags: javascript, date, object, time

The **problem** is, I would like to make the ***array of dates an object with key value pair***. Here is the array:

```
let array1 = ["2020 01 12T19:00:00",
        "2019 12 30T19:00:00",
        "2019 12 27T19:00:00",
        "2019 12 25T19:00:00",
        "2019 12 06T11:00:00",
        "2019 12 02T19:00:00",
        "2019 12 02T07:00:00",
        "2020 01 25T17:00:00",
        "2020 01 13T23:00:00",
        "2019 10 28T17:00:00",
        "2019 05 27T18:00:00",
        "2019 02 28T17:00:00",
        "2019 02 27T18:00:00",
        "2019 01 28T17:00:00"]
```

Then, *I would like to convert it to*: //currently I'm doing this on react

```
let bookedDates = {};

if(array1.length !== 0) {
 array1.map(el => {
  bookedDates = { moment(el, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').format('YYYY MM DD') : moment(el, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').format('h:mm A');
 }
}
```

**Notice** that what I would like to output is {DATE:TIME}.
I don't want them to be inserted in the object separately, because I need the value(TIME), if a specific data matches the key(DATE). Then, I would do:

```
if (Object.keys(bookedDates) === (moment(value ))) { // got from the data outside
      console.log(moment(bookedDates, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').format('h:mm A'));
}
```

Please Help! :( Or if you have any suggestions, Please feel free to post

Comment: The format string for parsing is incorrect, to match the sample data it should be `moment(el, 'YYYY MM DDTHH:mm:ss')`, i.e. no dashes between the date parts and no Z.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, Hope this Helps. **Note** require the `moment`

```
let array1 =  ["2020 01 12T19:00:00", 
               "2019 12 30T19:00:00",  
               "2019 12 27T19:00:00", 
               "2019 12 25T19:00:00", 
               "2019 12 06T11:00:00", 
               "2019 12 02T19:00:00",  
               "2019 12 02T07:00:00", 
               "2020 01 25T17:00:00", 
               "2020 01 13T23:00:00", 
               "2019 10 28T17:00:00",  
               "2019 05 27T18:00:00", 
               "2019 02 28T17:00:00",  
               "2019 02 27T18:00:00", 
               "2019 01 28T17:00:00"]

let bookedDates={} 
array1.map(arr=>{
    bookedDates[moment(arr,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').format('YYYY MM DD')] = moment(arr,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').format('h:mm A') })

console.log("obj",bookedDates) // Expected Output
```

*Then you add your Logic*

```
if (Object.keys(bookedDates) === (moment(value ))) { // got from the data outside
      console.log(moment(bookedDates, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').format('h:mm A'));
}
```

Suppose you got a result in this Format and you want to access the value according to the key and you have a key(date)

```js
// above output 
var bookedDates={
    '2019 01 28': "5:00 PM",
    '2019 02 27': "6:00 PM",
    '2019 02 28': "5:00 PM",
    '2019 05 27': "6:00 PM",
    '2019 10 28': "5:00 PM",
    '2019 12 02': "7:00 AM",
    '2019 12 06': "11:00 AM",
    '2019 12 25': "7:00 PM",
    '2019 12 27': "7:00 PM",
    '2019 12 30': "7:00 PM",
    '2020 01 12': "7:00 PM",
    '2020 01 13': "11:00 PM",
    '2020 01 25': "5:00 PM",
}

// suppose you have the date
var value ='2019 10 28'
var finalValue= bookedDates[value]
console.log(finalValue)
```

Comment: it Worked! thank you so much! However, do you know how will I get the value(time) of the Object.keys(date) that was matched to the value(data) ? Thanks again!

Comment: can you let me know what will be value(time) //suppose

Comment: @Heisenberg i have add the logic please have a look. if you feel the answer resolved your problem then mark the answer has correct, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The object key value is already present in the timestamps, it doesn't seem efficient to convert them to moment.js objects just to get back the same string.

The value is just 24 hour time converted to 12 hour am/pm time, so not difficult to convert without a large library. E.g.

```js
let data = [
  "2020 01 12T19:00:00",
  "2019 12 30T19:00:00",
  "2019 12 27T19:00:00",
  "2019 12 25T19:00:00",
  "2019 12 06T11:00:00",
  "2019 12 02T19:00:00",
  "2019 12 02T07:00:00",
  "2020 01 25T17:00:00",
  "2020 01 13T23:00:00",
  "2019 10 28T17:00:00",
  "2019 05 27T18:00:00",
  "2019 02 28T17:00:00",
  "2019 02 27T18:00:00",
  "2019 01 28T17:00:00"
]

// Convert time in HH:mm:ss format to hh:mm a/p
function hrsToAP(v) {
  let [h, m, s] = v.split(':');
  let ap = h < 12? 'AM' : 'PM';
  h = h % 12 || 12;
  return h + ':' + m + ' ' + ap;
}

let dateTime = data.reduce((acc, v) => {
  let [d, t] = v.split('T');
  acc[d] = hrsToAP(t);
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(dateTime);
```

I don't understand what you mean by:

> what I would like to output is {DATE:TIME}. I don't want them to be
>   inserted in the object separately, because I need the value(TIME), if
>   a specific data matches the key(DATE). Then, I would do:
>
> ```
> if (Object.keys(bookedDates) === (moment(value ))) { // got from the data outside
>   console.log(moment(bookedDates, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').format('h:mm A')); 
> }
> ```

`Object.keys` returns an array, `moment(value)` returns an object, those two objects will never be equal to each other. What you might have meant is:

```
Object.keys(bookedDates).includes(moment(value).format('YYYY MM DD'))
```

where the keys have the appropriate format. But it would be much simpler to do:

```
if (bookedDates[value.split('T')[0]]) {
  // date is in bookedDates
}
```

There are likely other approaches using [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) that may be more appropriate.